# ERROR 2103: doing work on Longs

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have data

```
store   trn_date    dept_id sale_amt
1       2014-12-15  101     10007655
1       2014-12-15  101     10007654
1       2014-12-15  101     10007544
6       2014-12-15  104     100086544
8       2014-12-14  101     1000000
8       2014-12-15  101     100865761
```

I'm trying to aggregate the data using below code -
Loading the data (tried both the way using HCatLoader() and using PigStorage())

```
data = LOAD 'data' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

group_table = GROUP data BY (store, tran_date, dept_id);

group_gen = FOREACH grp_table GENERATE 
           FLATTEN(group) AS (store, tran_date, dept_id),
           SUM(table.sale_amt) AS tota_sale_amt;
```

Below is the Error stack Trace which I'm getting while running the job

```
================================================================================
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2103: Problem doing work on Longs

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: grouped_all: Local Rearrange[tuple]{tuple}(false) - scope-1317 Operator Key: scope-1317): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem doing work on Longs
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:289)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POLocalRearrange.getNextTuple(POLocalRearrange.java:263)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigCombiner$Combine.processOnePackageOutput(PigCombiner.java:183)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigCombiner$Combine.reduce(PigCombiner.java:161)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigCombiner$Combine.reduce(PigCombiner.java:51)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:770)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2103: Problem doing work on Longs
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase.doTupleWork(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:84)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase$Intermediate.exec(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:108)
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase$Intermediate.exec(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNext(POUserFunc.java:330)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.POUserFunc.getNextTuple(POUserFunc.java:369)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.getNext(PhysicalOperator.java:333)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.processPlan(POForEach.java:378)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POForEach.getNextTuple(POForEach.java:298)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.PhysicalOperator.processInput(PhysicalOperator.java:281)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
        at org.apache.pig.builtin.AlgebraicLongMathBase.doTupleWork(AlgebraicLongMathBase.java:77)
================================================================================
```

As i was looking for solution, many of said it is due to loading the data using HCatalog Loader. so i have tried loading the data using **"PigStorage()"**.
still getting the same error.

Comment: Do a DESCRIBE on data and see if you have the correct data types

Comment: Thanks Fred, let me try!!

Comment: nothing wrong with data type, Still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically each aggregation function returns data with it's default data type,

```
Like -
AVG returns DOUBLE
SUM returns DOUBLE
COUNT returns LONG
```

I don't think so this is the issue while storing it into hive because you already tried PigStore() it means, it's just data type issue while you are passing it to aggregation.
Try to change the data type before passing it to aggregation and try.

Comment: @Bector, could you please post your working solution so that we can also get an insight of your work?

Answer (score 3):

This is may be because of the way you are storing data in hive. If any aggregation is going to happen on any column do mention it's **data type integer or numeric**.